# MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command getMore failed: BSONObj size: 45888169 (0x2BC32A9) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am facing this issue on prod while trying to transfer data from 1st collection to 2nd collection.
Getting this error.

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command getMore failed: BSONObj size: 45888169 (0x2BC32A9) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)

I have checked document size of these two tables by using below script but did not found any higher size document in both collection.

```
user=db.getSiblingDB('DB')
user.Coll.find().forEach(function(obj)
{
  var size = Object.bsonsize(obj);
  print('_id: '+obj._id+' || Size: '+size+'B -> '+Math.round(size/(1024))+'KB -> '+Math.round(size/(1024*1024))+'MB (max 16MB)');
});
```

my MongoDB version is 3.2. due to this my Table insertion failing is there any solution on this.

New table got failed getting below Error.

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed:
> BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB
> limit..

Can you build this query.

```
Aggregate Error {
  "connectionString": "mongodb://user:pass@hostname:27017/DB?authSource=admin",
  "databaseName": "DB",
  "collectionName": "Coll85",
  "matchCondition": {
    "TaskInstanceID": [
      "System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "$eq",
      851504966
    ],
    "_version": [
      "System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "$ne",
      -1
    ],
    "MatchStatus": [
      "System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "$ne",
      21
    ],
    "ViewData": [
      "System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "$ne",
      null
    ],
    "ViewData.CombinedAndIsPaired": [
      "System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "$ne",
      true
    ]
  },
  "groupCondition": [
    "ViewData.Status",
    "ViewData.Investment Type"
  ],
  "outColumns": [
    "InternalComment1",
    "InternalComment2",
    "InternalComment3",
    "ExternalComment1",
    "ExternalComment2",
    "ExternalComment3",
    "ViewData.Side0_UniqueIds",
    "ViewData.Side1_UniqueIds"
  ],
  "outputCollectionName": null,
  "returnOutput": true,
  "takeFirstInGroup": false,
  "getGroupCount": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not support documents, that have size more then 16MB. Your document is 45MB. That's not going to work. You have to reduce size of the document. Split it or remove data, which could be removed.

Comment: but as per my observation there is no document is getting create above 16MB in Collection A and B. where I can get that document which is getting create above 16MB.

Comment: @YogeshJ Messages you are observing beg to differ. Your problem is the size of the document.

Comment: Can you help me in building query from Error msg which I have updated in post.