# How to find objectId as an foreign key in mongo

Tags: mongodb, objectid, mongodb-compass

How can I find the value of **ObjectId** in whole database for any field in mongo ,
it  might be use in some collections for various fields as a reference?

```
   "fourk_runs": [{
        "Objectid": "6299b9f00f09ff045cc15d"
    }],
    "fourk_pass_fail": [{
        "Objectid": "6299b9f00f09ff045cc152"
    }],
    "dr_runs": [{
        "Objectid": "6299b9f00f09ff045cc154"
    }],
```

I try this command , but it does not work
`db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "4c8a331bda76c559ef04" } } )`

Comment: What's your collection's name?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, the references are mostly used for the normalization process. The references from the children's table (usually an ObjectID) are then embedded in the parent table. When reading the information, the user has to perform several queries in order to retrieve data from multiple collections.

For example, we will take the next two collections, parts and products. A product will contain many parts that will be referenced in the product collection.

parts Collection:

> db.parts.findOne()

```
{
    _id : ObjectID('1111'),
    partno : '7624-faef-2615',
    name : 'bearing',
    price: 20,000
}
```

products Collection:

> db.products.findOne()

```
{
    name : 'wheel',
    manufacturer : 'BMW',
    catalog_number: 1134,
    parts : [     // array of references to Part documents
        ObjectID('1111'),    // reference to the bearing above
        ObjectID('3f3g'),    // reference to a different Part
        ObjectID('234r'),
        // etc
    ]
}
```

To receive the parts for a particular product, we will first have to fetch the product document identified by the catalog number:

```
db.products.findOne({catalog_number: 1134});
```

Then, fetch all the parts that are linked to this product:

```
db.parts.find({_id: { $in : product.parts } } ).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your description, but my main problem is   **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031819/mongodb-driver-mongocommandexception-command-getmore-failed-bsonobj-size-4588**,  I do not know which field cause this issue, I wonder how can I  iterate throughout record to find a field more than 16

Comment: @faezehkermani Your question differs from the link you attached. what is your exact error?

Comment: This is error .MongoError: BSONObj size: 18269098 (0x116C3AA) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: ObjectId('61f87d68dc7e94f61b29ce0'), _How can I solve this ?

Comment: that's too dirty. It is better to get the size of the documents first and then perform mathematical calculations and print the value in another function. To find the size of all documents in a collection:
```Object.bsonsize(db.collection.find( {dbname:"collectionname"}))```

Comment: Thanks , it is really weird , none of collections more than 16MB, even more than 2MB, is it possible before insert to collection , the error occurs?